# "Connection refused" when try connect to Cloud SQL from a Symfony application deployed on App Engine Standard

Tags: symfony, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have changed the Symfony demo application configuration from SQLite to MySQL. Locally it works fine for me, but if I try to deploy it in the Google App Engine Standard environment it doesn't work.

It is not clear to me how I should put the connection string if the database is in Google Cloud SQL. Currently the project's `.env` file has this:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://dbname=THEDATABASENAME;unix_socket=PROJECTNAME:ZONE:INSTANCENAME"
```

I'm not sure if it's correct, or if something is missing, or if I need to configure something else in Symfony or in the Google Cloud Console.

When I deploy and browse to the site, I'm having Error 500.

The error log shows this:

```
2022-11-02 14:41:00 default[20221102t151407]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302
2022-11-02 14:41:01 default[20221102t151407]  nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /tmp/google-config/nginx.conf:3
2022-11-02 14:41:03 default[20221102t151407]  "GET /es HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-02 14:41:03 default[20221102t151407]  "GET /build/app.c5bd2611.js HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-02 14:41:03 default[20221102t151407]  "GET /build/runtime.725dd7e0.js HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-02 14:41:03 default[20221102t151407]  "GET /build/755.5a8586e9.js HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-02 14:41:03 default[20221102t151407]  "GET /build/95.1ed6b32f.js HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-02 14:41:03 default[20221102t151407]  "GET /build/app.17316efd.css HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-02 14:41:03 default[20221102t151407]  "GET /build/fonts/fa-solid-900.1551f4f6.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-02 14:41:03 default[20221102t151407]  "GET /build/fonts/fa-regular-400.7a333762.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-02 14:41:03 default[20221102t151407]  "GET /build/95.22c66ae4.css HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-02 14:41:03 default[20221102t151407]  "GET /build/823.168b723b.js HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-02 14:41:03 default[20221102t151407]  "GET /build/31.46aa6824.js HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-02 14:41:03 default[20221102t151407]  "GET /build/fonts/lato-bold.21b3848a.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-02 14:41:03 default[20221102t151407]  "GET /build/fonts/lato-normal.75614cfc.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-02 14:41:08 default[20221102t151407]  "GET /es/blog/ HTTP/1.1" 500
2022-11-02 14:41:09 default[20221102t151407]  [02-Nov-2022 14:41:09] WARNING: [pool app] child 20 said into stderr: "{"message":"Matched route \"blog_index\".","context":{"route":"blog_index","route_parameters":{"_route":"blog_index","page":"1","_format":"html","_controller":"App\\Controller\\BlogController::index","_locale":"es"},"request_uri":"https://testMYPROJECT.uc.r.appspot.com/es/blog/","method":"GET"},"level":200,"level_name":"INFO","channel":"request","datetime":"2022-11-02T14:41:08.499913+00:00","extra":{}}"
2022-11-02 14:41:09 default[20221102t151407]  [02-Nov-2022 14:41:09] WARNING: [pool app] child 20 said into stderr: "{"message":"Checking for authenticator support.","context":{"firewall_name":"main","authenticators":1},"level":100,"level_name":"DEBUG","channel":"security","datetime":"2022-11-02T14:41:08.500353+00:00","extra":{}}"
2022-11-02 14:41:09 default[20221102t151407]  [02-Nov-2022 14:41:09] WARNING: [pool app] child 20 said into stderr: "{"message":"Checking support on authenticator.","context":{"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\FormLoginAuthenticator"},"level":100,"level_name":"DEBUG","channel":"security","datetime":"2022-11-02T14:41:08.500361+00:00","extra":{}}"
2022-11-02 14:41:09 default[20221102t151407]  [02-Nov-2022 14:41:09] WARNING: [pool app] child 20 said into stderr: "{"message":"Authenticator does not support the request.","context":{"firewall_name":"main","authenticator":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Authenticator\\FormLoginAuthenticator"},"level":100,"level_name":"DEBUG","channel":"security","datetime":"2022-11-02T14:41:08.500367+00:00","extra":{}}"
2022-11-02 14:41:09 default[20221102t151407]  [02-Nov-2022 14:41:09] WARNING: [pool app] child 20 said into stderr: "{"message":"Failed to save key \"App%5CController%5CBlogController\" of type array: fopen(/workspace/var/cache/prod/pools/system/qGYD7CGfrN/d7b0f5b96ec8): Failed to open stream: Read-only file system","context":{"key":"App%5CController%5CBlogController","exception":{"class":"ErrorException","message":"fopen(/workspace/var/cache/prod/pools/system/qGYD7CGfrN/d7b0f5b96ec8): Failed to open stream: Read-only file system","code":0,"file":"/workspace/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:99"},"cache-adapter":"Symfony\\Component\\Cache\\Adapter\\PhpFilesAdapter"},"level":300,"level_name":"WARNING","channel":"cache","datetime":"2022-11-02T14:41:08.528050+00:00","extra":{}}"
2022-11-02 14:41:09 default[20221102t151407]  [02-Nov-2022 14:41:09] WARNING: [pool app] child 20 said into stderr: "{"message":"Failed to save key \"ea12799f***********\" of type Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\ParserResult: fopen(/workspace/var/cache/prod/pools/system/16ctGUzn1Q/774b86986a15): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory","context":{"key":"ea12799f**********","exception":{"class":"ErrorException","message":"fopen(/workspace/var/cache/prod/pools/system/16ctGU**********): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory","code":0,"file":"/workspace/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:99"},"cache-adapter":"Symfony\\Component\\Cache\\Adapter\\PhpFilesAdapter"},"level":300,"level_name":"WARNING","channel":"cache","datetime":"2022-11-02T14:41:09.092063+00:00","extra":{}}"
2022-11-02 14:41:09 default[20221102t151407]  [02-Nov-2022 14:41:09] WARNING: [pool app] child 20 said into stderr: "{"message":"Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\ConnectionException: \"An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused\" at /workspace/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/API/MySQL/ExceptionConverter.php line 101","context":{"exception":{"class":"Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\ConnectionException","message":"An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused","code":2002,"file":"/workspace/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/API/MySQL/ExceptionConverter.php:101","previous":{"class":"Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDO\\Exception","message":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused","code":2002,"file":"/workspace/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/PDO/Exception.php:28","previous":{"class":"PDOException","message":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused","code":2002,"file":"/workspace/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/PDO/MySQL/Driver.php:28"}}}},"level":500,"level_name":"CRITICAL","chann"
2022-11-02 14:41:09 default[20221102t151407]  [02-Nov-2022 14:41:09] WARNING: [pool app] child 20 said into stderr: "el":"request","datetime":"2022-11-02T14:41:09.173672+00:00","extra":{}}"
2022-11-02 14:41:09 default[20221102t151407]  [02-Nov-2022 14:41:09] WARNING: [pool app] child 20 said into stderr: "{"message":"Failed to save key \"Symfony%5CComponent%5CHttpKernel%5CController%5CErrorController\" of type array: fopen(/workspace/var/cache/prod/pools/system/qGYD7CGfrN/d7b0f5b96ec8): Failed to open stream: Read-only file system","context":{"key":"Symfony%5CComponent%5CHttpKernel%5CController%5CErrorController","exception":{"class":"ErrorException","message":"fopen(/workspace/var/cache/prod/pools/system/qGYD7CGfrN/d7b0f5b96ec8): Failed to open stream: Read-only file system","code":0,"file":"/workspace/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:99"},"cache-adapter":"Symfony\\Component\\Cache\\Adapter\\PhpFilesAdapter"},"level":300,"level_name":"WARNING","channel":"cache","datetime":"2022-11-02T14:41:09.191792+00:00","extra":{}}"
2022-11-02 14:41:09 default[20221102t151407]  [02-Nov-2022 14:41:09] WARNING: [pool app] child 20 said into stderr: "{"message":"Failed to save key \"Symfony%5CComponent%5CHttpKernel%5CController%5CErrorController%23__invoke\" of type array: fopen(/workspace/var/cache/prod/pools/system/qGYD7CGfrN/d7b0f5b96ec8): Failed to open stream: Read-only file system","context":{"key":"Symfony%5CComponent%5CHttpKernel%5CController%5CErrorController%23__invoke","exception":{"class":"ErrorException","message":"fopen(/workspace/var/cache/prod/pools/system/qGYD7CGfrN/d7b0f5b96ec8): Failed to open stream: Read-only file system","code":0,"file":"/workspace/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:99"},"cache-adapter":"Symfony\\Component\\Cache\\Adapter\\PhpFilesAdapter"},"level":300,"level_name":"WARNING","channel":"cache","datetime":"2022-11-02T14:41:09.192185+00:00","extra":{}}"
2022-11-02 14:41:09 default[20221102t151407]  [02-Nov-2022 14:41:09] WARNING: [pool app] child 20 said into stderr: "{"message":"Failed to save key \"Symfony%5CBundle%5CFrameworkBundle%5CController%5CTemplateController\" of type array: fopen(/workspace/var/cache/prod/pools/system/qGYD7CGfrN/d7b0f5b96ec8): Failed to open stream: Read-only file system","context":{"key":"Symfony%5CBundle%5CFrameworkBundle%5CController%5CTemplateController","exception":{"class":"ErrorException","message":"fopen(/workspace/var/cache/prod/pools/system/qGYD7CGfrN/d7b0f5b96ec8): Failed to open stream: Read-only file system","code":0,"file":"/workspace/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:99"},"cache-adapter":"Symfony\\Component\\Cache\\Adapter\\PhpFilesAdapter"},"level":300,"level_name":"WARNING","channel":"cache","datetime":"2022-11-02T14:41:09.700565+00:00","extra":{}}"
2022-11-02 14:41:09 default[20221102t151407]  [02-Nov-2022 14:41:09] WARNING: [pool app] child 20 said into stderr: "{"message":"Failed to save key \"Symfony%5CBundle%5CFrameworkBundle%5CController%5CTemplateController%23templateAction\" of type array: fopen(/workspace/var/cache/prod/pools/system/qGYD7CGfrN/d7b0f5b96ec8): Failed to open stream: Read-only file system","context":{"key":"Symfony%5CBundle%5CFrameworkBundle%5CController%5CTemplateController%23templateAction","exception":{"class":"ErrorException","message":"fopen(/workspace/var/cache/prod/pools/system/qGYD7CGfrN/d7b0f5b96ec8): Failed to open stream: Read-only file system","code":0,"file":"/workspace/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/FilesystemCommonTrait.php:99"},"cache-adapter":"Symfony\\Component\\Cache\\Adapter\\PhpFilesAdapter"},"level":300,"level_name":"WARNING","channel":"cache","datetime":"2022-11-02T14:41:09.701047+00:00","extra":{}}"
2022-11-02 14:41:09 default[20221102t151407]  "GET /build/fonts/fa-brands-400.d878b0a6.woff2 HTTP/1.1" 200
2022-11-02 14:41:09 default[20221102t151407]  "GET /build/css/app.4aa95248.css HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google App Engine (Standard) docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard) for connecting to Cloud SQL note that:

> Once correctly configured, you can connect your service to your Cloud SQL instance's Unix domain socket accessed on the environment's filesystem at the following path: /cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME

Your `unix_socket` value above should be:

```
/cloudsql/project:region:instance-id
```

rather than just

```
project:region:instance-id
```

Also note that it should be the *region*, not the zone, i.e., `northamerica-northeast1` rather than `northamerica-northeast1-a`. When in doubt, you can verify the connection name either:

- on the overview page in the console for the target SQL instance
- by running `gcloud sql instances describe INSTANCE_NAME`

---

Finally, you may also need to verify that:

- the service account for your App Engine service has the `Cloud SQL Client` role in the project hosting the SQL instance and the project hosting the App Engine service
- the Cloud SQL Admin API (`sqladmin.googleapis.com`) is enabled on both the project hosting the SQL instance and the project hosting the App Engine service

Comment: The App Engine Service and the Cloud SQL instance are in the same project and the service account of App Engine has the Cloud SQL Client role. Trying with this: `mysql://root:MYPWD@127.0.0.1/lDBNAME?serverVersion=8.0.26` I have the error: *connection refused*, and trying with `unix_socket=cloudsql/PROJECT:ZONE:INSTANCE;dbname=DBNAME` I have *file not found* error. NOTE: I'm trying directly in the URL, after deploy, not into my local machine.

Comment: @A.Cedano hmmm... that `unix_socket` argument doesn't look quite right. It should be:

`unix_socket=/cloudsql/PROJECT:REGION:INSTANCE`

Note the leading `/` (i.e., `/cloudsql` instead of `cloudsql`) and that you should use the _region_, not the zone.

Comment: That was exactly the error, I was missing the initial `/` character before `cloudsql`. On the other hand, I was trying to connect with a user other than `root`, believing that creating it would give me access to the database, but no, I had to give it privileges to connect to that database. Doing both, it has worked. Thank you for your invaluable help.